# Changed root directory's permissions to 644, how can I change it back?

Tags: permissions, root

I changed the root directory's permissions to 664. Now my display and keyboard are disabled. How can I change it back ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to boot the system with a Live CD and see if you can change the permissions on the root directory by mounting the hardrive as a secondary device.

You'll need to know which were the permissions by default.

Answer (score 0):

In simple:

Try to boot from a Live Cd/DVD/USB.

When you are in mount your booting parition and then

```
chmod 700 /path-to-mounted-partition/root
```